# Error returning boolean in Swagger-Node

Tags: swagger, swagger-node-express

I'm new to swagger-node and I am creating an API method that returns data of type boolean. The yaml of the method is:

```
  /IsBooting: 
  get: 
    summary: "Returns if the device is booting"
    description: "Returns true when  is in booting state"
    x-swagger-router-controller: printer_status
    operationId: IsBooting
    responses: 
      200: 
        description: "Returns a bool that indicates if the deviceis booting"
        schema: 
          type: "boolean"
      default: 
        description: "Unexpected error"
        schema: 
          $ref: "#/definitions/Error"
```

The method in the controller that this API method call is:

```
function IsBooting(req, res) {
   res.json(false)
}
```

When I call this method using PostMan, some validations fails with this message:

```
Error: Response validation failed: not a valid boolean: false
    at throwErrorWithCode (C:\...\node_modules\swagger-express-mw\node_modules\swagger-node-runner\node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\validators.js:121:13)
    at validateTypeAndFormat (C:\...\node_modules\swagger-express-mw\node_modules\swagger-node-runner\node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\validators.js:536:7)
    at Object.module.exports.validateSchemaConstraints (C:\...\node_modules\swagger-express-mw\node_modules\swagger-node-runner\node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\validators.js:627:7)
    at validateValue (C:\...\node_modules\swagger-express-mw\node_modules\swagger-node-runner\node_modules\swagger-tools\middleware\swagger-validator.js:117:16)
    at ServerResponse.res.end (C:\...\node_modules\swagger-express-mw\node_modules\swagger-node-runner\node_modules\swagger-tools\middleware\swagger-validator.js:242:9)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:204:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\...\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:249:15)
    at IsBooting (C:\...\api\controllers\printer_status.js:54:7)
    at swaggerRouter (C:\...\node_modules\swagger-express-mw\node_modules\swagger-node-runner\node_modules\swagger-tools\middleware\swagger-router.js:407:20)
    at swagger_router (C:\...\node_modules\swagger-express-mw\node_modules\swagger-node-runner\fittings\swagger_router.js:31:5)
```

I don't know how to make a response that contains the data. I cand send it if I use a string as type, or if I create a new complex type that encapsulates the boolean, but I think that there are not very good solutions...

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

The swagger has DataType for boolean:
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/

The most correct would be to create a schema definition for the answer:

```
    responses:
      "200":
        description: Success
        schema:
          type: "#/definitions/TrueReponsenDefinition"
```

Make the proper definition, for this case:

```
      TrueReponsenDefinition:
        title: A bool that indicates if the deviceis booting
        type: boolean
        properties:
          booted:
            type: boolean
```

Response from the node, would be:

```
  const data = {
    booted: true,
  };
  return res.status(httpStatus.OK).json(data);
```

Note that the most appropriate would be to encapsulate the data. In this case, we use "booted"

The body of the answer will be:

```
{
  "booted": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue. I just changed the response schema type to string.
In a sense, all http response will be string, and you would need to parse it to convert to types you would use in your application.

This is my swagger spec.

```
responses:
'200':
  description: a string that represents a boolean value
  schema:
    type: string
```

Comment: Finally I do the same, I couldn't find a workaround :(

Answer (score 1):

**In Swagger 3.0.0**

```
   responses:
    '200':
      description: Success
      content:
        application/json:
          schema:
            type: object
            items: 
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/TrueReponsenDefinition"
```

and Components/Schemas defintion will be:

```
components:
schemas:
TrueReponsenDefinition:
  title: A bool that indicates if the app notification is ON/OFF
  type: object
  properties:
    appNotificationOn:
      type: boolean
```

Response will be JSON object:

```
{
 "appNotificationOn":boolean
 }
```